# Digit recognition with Tesseract OCR and c#

Tags: c#, ocr, tesseract

I use Tesseract and C# to read digits. Everything works well except for the number "8". Tesseract can not read the "8" Digit.
This is the picture I send to tesseract :

[image]

And tesseract reads "50005550055".
this is my method :

```
public string Process(Bitmap bitmap, MetaTraderObjects metaObjects, bool isNumber = false)
{
    try
    {
        var graphicLib = new GraphicLib();
        bitmap = graphicLib.PerformReadingTextEffects(bitmap.ToBytes(), metaObjects).ToBitmap();
        var result = "";
        var enginePath = Const.BaseAppPath + "\\tessdata";
        using (var engine = new TesseractEngine(enginePath, "eng", EngineMode.Default))
        {
            var ver = engine.Version;
            using (var img = Pix.LoadTiffFromMemory(graphicLib.ConvertBitMapToByteArray(bitmap.ToBytes())))
            {
                using (var page = engine.Process(img,(PageSegMode)8))
                {
                    var text = page.GetText();
                    result = TextReformer.Reform(text, isNumber);
                    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bitmap.ToBytes());
                    Image i = Image.FromStream(ms);
                }
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ExceptionLog.Handel(ex);
        return null;
    }
}
```

How can I tell Tesseract that the vertical rod is a "8"?

Comment: Which version of Tesseract are you using?

Comment: It's been a long time since I worked with Tesseract, but I remember having to expand images to double their width and height to get better results in general, not related to a specific character.  Not sure if that will help here or not.

Comment: @AbdelAzizAbdelLatef 3.3.0.0

Comment: @juharr Anything you know might be helpful!

Comment: Tesseract recommends at least 300 DPI for best results. In my experience 200 is pretty decent. Your characters are about 8 pixels wide right now; 20 would work much better.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you use the latest version of Tesseract. It could perform better.

[Tesseract 4.1.0](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/releases/tag/4.1.0)

Comment: how can i use this in c#?

Comment: I think this may help you https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/ocr-using-tesseract-in-C-Sharp/